# Регулярные выражения. Максимальное вхождения

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

```
import re

def findLongest(s):
    try:
        result = max(re.findall(r'((\w+?)\2+)', s), key=lambda t: len(t[0]))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        return result

mystr = "helloworld world world hellohellohelloworldworld"
print(findLongest(mystr))
```

Выводит

> > (output): ('hellohellohello', 'hello')

А нужно,чтобы вывело world, так как эта последовательность встречается чаще всего. Что не так?

Выражение должно искать вхождение, которое глобально повторяется наибольшее количество раз

Comment: Дайте определение понятию "вхождение". Является ли одна буква вхождением? А две буквы?

Answer (score 0):

В качестве ключа используем количество вхождений подстроки в строку:

```
import re

def find_longest(text):
    return max(re.findall(r'((\w+?)\2+)', text), key=lambda t: t[0].count(t[1]))

text = "helloworld world world hellohellohelloworldworld"
print(find_longest(text))  # ('hellohellohello', 'hello')
```

Можно попробовать выцепить отдельные слова и после посчитать их вхождение в текст, например:

```
def find_longest(text):
    words = set(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text))
    return max([(w, text.count(w)) for w in words], key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

text = "helloworld world world hellohellohelloworldworld"
print(find_longest(text))  # world
```

Comment: должно же вывести 
#world

Comment: мда... а как разделять слипшиеся слова? :) точнее, как понять что `helloworld` это два слова, а не одно?

Comment: text = "hello hellohellohello worldabraworldhemiworldhuiworldsworldpdsaworlduiworld"
неправильно выводит(
Это вообще реально с помощью регулярных выражений?
@gil9red

Comment: @DanielSadovskiy, в текущей постановке задачи я сделал что мог. Сложно сказать реально или нет, пока не известная сама задача

Comment: вывести вхождение ПОДСТРОКИ, которое встречается наиболее часто. Тоесть строка : "hfdaikseniadsa aabbb hefllokseniaworld auksaf mbksenia" 
чаще всего тут встречается ksenia: "hfdaiKSENIAdsa aabbb heflloKSENIAworld auksaf mbKSENIA"

Comment: наибольшее число самой длинной
то есть если две подпоследовательно встречаются одинаково максимально, то вывести ту, которая длинее

Comment: @DanielSadovskiy, это вам кажется что `KSENIA` самая частая подстрока, а ведь там на самом деле это `a` -- эта подстрока чаще остальных встречается в тексте: `from collections import Counter
print(Counter("hfdaikseniadsa aabbb hefllokseniaworld auksaf mbksenia"))`